# How do I fix this issue with smart filter? (Photoshop CS6)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, smartobject

I was testing out a new filter I recently bought, and I liked the result. But I wasn't able to edit some of the Smart Filters, because of the smart filter showing me this (I wonder why, because I haven't done anything much):

[image: the filter]

Any help? I'm still a bit new to Photoshop as well.

**Edit:** it has “filter not available or applicable on this document” warning

**Edit (2)**: the version used is Adobe Photoshop Version: 13.0 (13.0 20120315.r.428 2012/03/15:21:00:00) x64

Also, the question asked: what and how to actually adjust the smart filters since despite it's for CS6, it has the warning sign despite I changed color mode from RGB to CMYK, and color channels from 8 bit to 16 bit etc.?

I bought a filter online, and it's hard to be refunded, I liked the results. But I just can't adjust some setting because of the warning sign near the smart filter adjustments (some filter can be adjusted however except invert, bnw, threshold, and levels).

Thanks to anyone who answered.

Comment: I am sorry but what are you trying to ask exactly?

Comment: If you *purchased* a plug in which allows adjustments such as Black & White or Levels as Smart Filters, and it's not working.... You need to contact the *plugin manufacturer*. You haven't even named the plug in here.

Comment: There is a possibility that changing the image mode to CMYK and changing to 16bit is the problem. If I remember  correctly, in older versions of Photoshop, not all filters/adjustments worked in these modes. Try converting back to RGB and 8bit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CS6 does not support levels as smart filters.  It's probably because of that.  Maybe you have a file open that was saved in a newer version or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, but the one I bought off was tailored for CS6 so it's really weird at this point.